# Why is 'cars %>% filter (cylinders == 8, mpg > 18)' returning an incorrect value in R?

Tags: r

My code is: `cars %>% filter (cylinders == 8, mpg > 18)` and is returning the results shown in the photo attached -

[image]

The results are all correct aside from the top row which has a mpg of 9. Why is this result being included and how do I rectify this?

Comment: In the future, please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly (using a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the numeric columns in your dataset are of type character where `"9" > "18"` returns `TRUE` because they are compared alphabetically and not numerically. Change them to numeric and your code should work.

```
library(dplyr)
cars <- type.convert(cars, as.is = TRUE)
cars %>% filter(cylinders == 8, mpg > 18)

#In base R : 
subset(cars, cylinders == 8 & mpg > 18)
```

`type.convert` will convert columns to their respective type.

Comment: Maybe also give a quick explanation why `"9" > "18"` ?